# How can I let wget to show file upload progress?

Tags: wget

I'm using wget to upload files using the POST method. Sometimes the file is quite big. Is there a way to show the progress, like it does with download?

Answer (score 12):

`wget` does not have a progress bar for file uploads, bur `curl` does. Use the `-T` to specify the file, and `-#` to specify that you want a progress bar. Here is an example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file count=4068
4068+0 records in
4068+0 records out
2082816 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.0459911 seconds, 45.3 MB/s
$ curl -T file -# -o output http://pastebin.com/
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

Comment: `-o output` is required, otherwise the progress bar will not show up.
This command can also be used for uploading files to MS SharePoint.

Comment: You can use `-o /dev/null` to still see a progress bar but not write output to file anywhere.